# loop though an array and return a set of array index's values concatenated in one variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean-operations

The question it's not so relevant but what I want to achieve is the next :

```
var some_array = [Modernizr.json, Modernizr.csstransforms];

var tests = function() {
    for (var i = some_array .length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       ...
    };

    return  Modernizr.json && Modernizr.csstransforms;
};
```

I keep thinking of the logic that would do what I tried to show you, but I cannot figure it out. Basically I need to loop the array of tests and return a boolean operation between the tests, to be more specific I want to take the array `[Modernizr.json, Modernizr.csstransforms]` and I want to return `Modernizr.json && Modernizr.csstransforms` and so on ( if there are more values in the array ).

Comment: you mean `var tests` ? no, it isn't, should it be ?

Comment: I don't know tbh. In it's current state I have no idea what it is you are looking for. Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: are you trying to do `some_array.join()` ?

Comment: I don't think so ... is it so hard to understand ? I want to get from an array to an boolean operation ( `&&` ) between the array values ... isn't this clear enough ? because I have no idea how to explain this in any other way (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
return some_array.reduce(function(a, b){ return a && b; });
```

or [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) if you want to iterate backwards.

If you want to break the loop once a falsy value is encountered, you also could use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Every).

Comment: `reduce` is not supported in IE8 and lower

Comment: and what if I have more than two values, what if there are 15 ? will the above statement still work ?

Comment: @Roland: `some_array` can be an array of any length (should be at least 2 for reducing)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if all values in your array are true, you can do this:

```
var some_array = [Modernizr.json, Modernizr.csstransforms];

var tests = function() {
    var result = true;
    for (var i = some_array .length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result = result && some_array[i];
    };
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution for what I was looking for, based on @Bergi's answer :

```
some_array.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
    return previousValue && currentValue;
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my solution…